# Issue with HTML5 date component not working with Cordova on iOS 14

Tags: html, cordova, ios14

When we edit or set any date or time field on an iOS device, an accordion wheel normally appears at the bottom of the device screen with which the user selects a date/time.
On iOS 14 this accordion wheel does not appear and the user is not able to change the date.

Answer (score 1):

After some research we found three alternatives to fix the issue:

1. Use Cordova date plugin instead of HTML5 date component (Refer:
   https://github.com/VitaliiBlagodir/cordova-plugin-datepicker)
2. Upgrade to Cordova@latest, Node@latest, cordova-ios@latest
3. Replace HTML5 date component with Angular Material DatetimePicker (Refer: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-material-components/datetime-picker)

- Option - 1 : did not work, it resulted in a blank screen
- Option - 2 : was not feasible as we have issue with UIWebView (we are still in migration process to WKWebView)
- Option -3 : Worked for us as we could replace the HTML5 Date component with Angular material component.